# Possible race condition with migration

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, vote-to-close

Definitely a bug. [One question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361881/why-the-stackoverflows-search-engine-is-so-poor-closed) was migrated with **six** close votes. It ended up making [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/why-the-stackoverflows-search-engine-is-so-poor) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19297/why-the-stackoverflows-search-engine-is-so-poor) on meta after migration.

Is this a race condition with the sixth vote causing the question to be migrated a second time? Could be fixed by either making sure six people can't close a question, or by checking to see if a question was already migrated before migrating it. Assuming that's what the problem is (I've been known to be wrong before).

Both questions on meta link back to the same question on SO, so they were definitely migrated twice from the same source. Additionally, the OP's profile contains only one closed question.

---

Further evidence: [the revision history of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1361881/list) is pretty clearly showing that it's been migrated twice because of the sixth close vote:

> Post Migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com by **Konrad Rudolph, Naveen, Shoban, Daniel Brückner, Yuval F**
>
> Post Migrated to meta.stackoverflow.com by **Konrad Rudolph, Naveen, Shoban, Daniel Brückner, Yuval F, SilentGhost**

Emphasis mine.

---

Looks like it's not fixed afterall: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2030983/list

Was migrated twice due to six close votes. I'm very disappointed in you, Angels.

Comment: ... which answers the question who would be the first to point out this bug (I had mine typed up already -- well, you beat me).

Comment: Bwahaha! Did you come to the same conclusion that I did?

Comment: Also, shame on you for trying to beat me, Welbog, at a typing race. I'm like a word wizard. A viscount of vocabulary. A sorcerer of salutations!

Comment: Na, I had a whole patch to the SO source code worked out which fixed the issue. It also made the badges a little shinier. But oh well... your question is fine, I guess.

Comment: I deleted the dup - but it definitely happened; I deliberately didn't "merge" it; even though that would have brought the comments over, it would have lost visibility of the 2nd question's existence.

Comment: I appreciate that, Marc. But couldn't you have just closed and locked it instead so that everyone can see it?

Comment: @balpha: Don't be so slow next time. I wrote Jeff Atwood 38 years ago in order to create something that would create badges in the first place.

Comment: Fine; closed and locked... not sure what people will see that is very different, though.

Comment: Well, if it's visible it's more likely people will understand there's actually a problem and might have more insight into it. I don't know. Do what you want. I'm not your mother.

Comment: No mother's day gift for you, then. Besides, there's no real *harm* in having it dup for a while... (since it can't do anything while closed+locked)

Comment: That's the spirit!

Comment: I feel like "since it can't do anything while closed and locked" is the opening for a cheesy horror movie, MSO style.

Comment: @Eric: We should make sure that there are no Zombie Questions... Get your close-shotgun handy!

Comment: Again, looks like this one isn't fixed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47244/why-new-user-is-created-everytime-on-stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47243/why-new-user-is-created-everytime-on-stackoverflow

Comment: It's showed up again, but in fiercer force than ever before! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915563/stackoverflow-reputation-repercussions has been migrated to meta 6 times now! [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/) is the one with answers in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug - for close votes, we're going to have to "lock" a question during the vote.  This won't affect other vote types.

Good find on this - working on it now!

**Update** - when fixing this, I'm shocked to admit I used a `goto` statement for the first time ever - I'd post the code, but I'm kinda ashamed :-P

But this problem is *hopefully* fixed on the next deployment!

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Post it! Post it! Post it!

Comment: Alas, programmers everywhere would see the code and then flee our site for another - probably one allowing professional gender reassignment.

Comment: Also, I could have used a `while (true)` loop, but I find that just as hacky as `goto` - this case was extremely localized; only 7 lines of code for the fix.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/- At my last job, doing COBOL, this got taped up to the wall.

Comment: @AgentConundrum - thank goodness I've got anti-raptor spray!

Comment: I can't upvote this. Not with a goto in it!

Comment: +1 I'll up-vote only because it's Jarrod. You don't get much opportunity to too otherwise. But GOTO? I suddenly see stream of the SO code-base in VB.Net.

Comment: **POST THE CODE, MAN**

Comment: Hey, this issue is back again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47243/why-new-user-is-created-everytime-on-stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47244/why-new-user-is-created-everytime-on-stackoverflow

Comment: The `goto` has been removed - I can sleep again.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it have something to do with the editing of the question? even though they are some ms apart, that's what could have triggered this.

Comment: I doubt it. Take a look at the original question's revisions: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1361881/list It's pretty clear that it was migrated once because `Konrad Rudolph, Naveen, Shoban, Daniel Brückner, Yuval F` voted to migrate, then again because `Konrad Rudolph, Naveen, Shoban, Daniel Brückner, Yuval F, SilentGhost` voted to migrate.

Comment: You are right, but what allowed for `Rudolph, Naveen, Shoban, Daniel Brückner, Yuval F` votes to be counted twice...

Comment: I'm guessing a race condition, like I said in the original post. I figure the migration routine checks for `>=5` on every vote, rather than `==5`. That way any vote 5 or over results in a migration, and a race condition allows there to be more than 5 votes.