# View highest-voted question by tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers

I am curious to know:

1. Who asked the highest-voted question?
2. What is the question?
3. Who had the highest-voted answer to the question?

There is no option currently in SO to view the highest-voted (most popular) question and answers in each tag.

It would be really nice to see this.

The hot listing only shows the top voted question (and that is off-topic).

Comment: This should be in meta.

Comment: why its duplicated migrating from SO... BUG??

Comment: @Ramesh http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Comment: @random.. got it.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easily possible to see the highest voted question by tag. Just click on the tag and then click the "votes" tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is already possible, using the SO Data Dump that's publicly available. Don't know exactly from where, though - I never used it myself...

Comment: mmm okie... but its really hard to see most popular questions using that option.. it would be nice if this is part of SO...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sandbox](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/) to do such queries. The [anatomy of a data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump) gives you the structure of the tables.

Just search for posts with the right PostTypeId for answer or question that include a certain tag in Tags, order by votes descending and retrieve just one record. You can the retrieve the user by OwnerUserId.

As Joel pointed out the highest voted question per tag is easily found. But in the sandbox you can search for other criteria as well. Just use standard SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/789876/highest-scoring-questions-and-answer-by-tag?TagName=java) does the job:

[image]

It returns [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4751173) as the highest scoring [java](/questions/tagged/java) question, and the highest scoring [java](/questions/tagged/java) answer is also on this question (but that could be different).

For reference, here is the complete query (it could probably be written in a more efficient way, but it's just an adaptation of [this query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306087/295232)):

```sql
SELECT TagName,
  QuestionID AS [Post Link], q_.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], q_.Score AS [Q score],
  AnswerID AS [Post Link], a_.OwnerUserId AS [User Link], a_.Score AS [A score]
FROM
(SELECT TagName,
  (SELECT TOP 1 q.Id
     FROM Posts AS q INNER JOIN PostTags AS qt ON q.Id = qt.PostId
     WHERE qt.TagId = t.Id ORDER BY q.Score DESC) AS QuestionID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 a.Id
     FROM Posts AS a INNER JOIN PostTags AS at ON a.ParentId = at.PostId
     WHERE at.TagId = t.Id ORDER BY a.Score DESC) AS AnswerID
  FROM Tags AS t
  WHERE t.TagName = ##TagName:string##) AS temp
  INNER JOIN Posts AS q_ ON temp.QuestionId = q_.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts AS a_ ON temp.AnswerId = a_.Id
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so the post scores could be a little bit off.