# Query to show the highest voted post in each tag

Tags: discussion, tags, data-explorer, score

Is there a query that will list the highest voted post (question or answer) for each tag on a site?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20176/feature-request-view-highest-voted-question-by-tag (this is only for one tag at time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/789841/highest-scoring-questions-and-answers-in-each-tag) I just wrote does the job.

[image]

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
SELECT TagName, QuestionID AS [Post Link], q_.Score AS [Q score],
  AnswerID AS [Post Link], a_.Score AS [A score]
FROM
(SELECT TagName,
  (SELECT TOP 1 q.Id
     FROM Posts AS q INNER JOIN PostTags AS qt ON q.Id = qt.PostId
     WHERE qt.TagId = t.Id ORDER BY q.Score DESC) AS QuestionID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 a.Id
     FROM Posts AS a INNER JOIN PostTags AS at ON a.ParentId = at.PostId
     WHERE at.TagId = t.Id ORDER BY a.Score DESC) AS AnswerID
  FROM Tags AS t) AS temp
  INNER JOIN Posts AS q_ ON temp.QuestionId = q_.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts AS a_ ON temp.AnswerId = a_.Id
  ORDER BY q_.Score DESC
```

and note that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Is there anyway to make some rows multi-line, so titles don't get cutoff?

Comment: Also, an interesting variation would be to make it so restrict it to certain tags. What I mean by that is restricting the query to only posts with the tag [tag:tags], for example.

Comment: @PyRulez no, but you can export to CSV, open with Excel and do anything you want with the data.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard The CSV doesn't have the post titles at all.

Comment: @PyRulez oh, didn't know.

Comment: @PyRulez multiline isn't possible, but you could resize the columns. You can also [fork](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/fork/789841) the query to create your own versions, e.g. [this one](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/789875) which shows only Java / JavaScript tags on Stack Overflow.