# How can a question be closed by a single (non-moderator) user?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close, self-close

Normally it takes five 3K+ users to close out a question for whatever reason they choose. Or in the case of a race to the finish line, [a sixth car will ghost past the checkered flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration).

If a moderator steps in, they have the power to close with their lone vote, [no matter however many have come before. None even](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question-in-stackoverflow-how-do-they-work/10583#10583).

But how does it happen when one user closes a question when the closer is not a moderator?

Case to the jury: [How to force PHP to use UTF-8 charset](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/286148/list)

How does something like that happen?

Comment: up down up down left right left right b a b a select start. That's how it happens.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Back in November of '08, it only took a single user (with at or above 3K reputation) to close a question. And users with considerably less reputation could close *their own* questions.

The "vote to close" system we all know and, uh, love... came later (December '08, AFAIK).