# Closing own question

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, self-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a question be closed by a single (non-moderator) user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/how-can-a-question-be-closed-by-a-single-non-moderator-user)

I've noticed a few people closing their own question as "off-topic", like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012/loading-assemblies-and-its-dependencies-closed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374/what-is-a-good-source-for-learning-olap-closed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360/moving-sql-based-reports-to-data-cubes-closed).  I didn't even know you could close your question by yourself, and it seems strange that it's happening at all.

Did I miss some new announcement?

Edit: Actually I see that these are very old questions, so now I'm even more confused.  Also there are many more examples, just do a search on SO for **closed:1**.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/question-closed-by-a-single-non-moderator-non-asker-vote-circumstances (the vote-to-close system was added later)

Comment: Thanks, voting to close.

Comment: Wow, lots of dupes. 15.4K can not close this! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closing+own+question

Comment: I asked this question before you too, unfortunately I can see it -- it was probably deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Voting to close your own question as off-topic seems pointless to me.  If I thought the question was off-topic, I wouldn't have posted it in the first place.

If the community thinks I posted a question that is off-topic, I just delete it.  If I really want an answer to my question, I may let the community close it down, to give it time to attract some answers.  But I never vote to close my own question.

There was one exception here on meta where a question I posted was no longer relevant, and it had already attracted some good answers and a close vote for being no longer relevant, so I threw my own close vote onto the pile.

Comment: Well, those questions were posted in the first month of the closed beta - it's possible delete wasn't working for normal users yet...

Comment: Sometimes I encounter obscure, bizarre problems and finally post a question in desperation. Once I solve the problem myself, I usually close my own (confusing WTF?) question. Example: I once had a file that would change it's bizarre behavior upon every new character of code I typed but never throw errors (was missing a semicolon).