# Closing my own question as a duplicate

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Askers should be able to close their own question as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64920/askers-should-be-able-to-close-their-own-question-as-a-duplicate)

I have just asked a question on SO, someone added a comment that pointed me to another question that I consider to be a duplicate, so I have voted to close my question.

However it still needs other people to vote.

Why do I have to vote to close my own question, why can’t I have a “casting vote” when closing my own question?

Comment: Duplicate of [allow question asker to close own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10363/145982), [Askers should be able to close their own question as a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64920/145982), [Closing own question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51588/145982), [Closing my Own Question still requires 5 Votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34864/145982), etc.

Comment: Is this irony ?

Comment: lol <hack the limit>