# Closing my question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)
> [Closing own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51588/closing-own-question)

How can I close my question.

I dont see the link or button to do so.

Questions in stackoverflow.

and why does

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

always happen. what are the quality standards?

Comment: These sites work best when you ask one question at a time. That'll help you get better answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51588/closing-own-question) for some explanation from a moderator.

However what you *can* do it delete your own question - if it has no upvoted answer it should be possible by just clicking the "delete" link that does appear beneath the question.

As for quality standards - using "i" instead of "I" is bad quality. Same for "ur" instead of "your" etc.

Also, code should be formatted by selecting it and clicking the code icon in the editor, or indenting it with four spaces.