# Make an OP close vote binding

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close

I know you can close a question as a duplicate when a close vote has been cast but can an OP close vote be binding even when not closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Note that back in the early years of SE, users [could in fact close their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20626/295232), but it was later removed because users were [closing their questions just because they were answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-voting-to-close-your-own-questions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t agree with this feature request.

The Original Poster can already close his question as a duplicate. Closing as a duplicate will help others with the same question to find an answer instead of deleting it.

Here are other close reasons as to which it would be better to delete or edit the question:

## Off-topic

If the question is a duplicate it is better off closed, that’s why you can close it. It can direct future visitors to the original question.

If the question is completely unrelated to the site it is better off deleted as it won’t help any future visitors.

If the question doesn’t have enough research it can be edited and not be closed. In turn it can help future visitors.

## Unclear what you’re asking

The question can be edited to be clearer which can hence help future visitors with the same question.

## Too broad

The question can be edited to be more specific which can help other users with the same problem.

## Primarily opinion based

The question can’t be given a definite answer and is better off deleted.