# Six people to close - bug?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639050/what-are-the-next-top-technologies-for-the-next-5-years-closed

Looks like six people listed as voting to close.  I was under the impression it should only list the first five.  Is this a bug?

Comment: +1 - Interesting find...

Comment: I'm glad at least my disaster question could help Matthew find something interesting...

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think two people cast the fifth vote at the same time.  If you look at [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1639050/list), you see two different "this post was closed by x" messages, with the same timestamp (to the second).

Comment: I smell a race condition!

Comment: Me too. It smells like... popcorn.

Comment: @Randolph, race conditions are only harmform when they change the outcome of the operation.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose two people could have voted at the same time.