# Migration => duplication?

Tags: bug, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible race condition with migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration)

This question has been asked on SO : [what language is Stackoverflow coded in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030983/what-language-is-stackoverflow-coded-in-closed) (id=2030983)

It's been migrated to meta, as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34961/what-language-is-stackoverflow-coded-in) (id=34961) *(when following the "migrated" link on SO )* -- of course, this one has now been closed as a duplicate.

But, on SO, there <s>is</s> was also another question (id=34963, now redacted) -- which seems to also be marked as "migrated from SO" ?

Now, what's funny :

- the two questions are the same
- theirs id are real close : 34961 and 34963
- they both have to comment I initially posted on SO (which seems to indicate both questions come from SO)
- It seems the question from SO has been migrated twice ?

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is related to the [six close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27608/six-people-to-close-bug) race condition.

Comment: hoho, I didn't even notice there were 6 "close" votes on the SO question ^^

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Greg has the truth of it; to tidy up, I've merged 34963 into 34961 (since the "migrated" link in the original question on SO referenced 34961).