# I just cast the sixth close vote on a question

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, closed-questions

> ### put on hold as off-topic by toro2k, Wayne Conrad, Uri Agassi, eugen, MikDiet, Undo 10 mins ago

Can anyone see the problem here? Yes, I just cast the sixth close vote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464198/calendar-with-current-user-events). Pretty much all I know is that it was from the review interface, and that the modal close-vote-thingy showed a total of five close votes on the question.

I, of course, think that we successfully taught that question a lesson and expect it to stay closed. But still, bug much?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27608/six-people-to-close-bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Comment: I agree with what's mentioned on the linked posts. Race condition; not harmful; so not really something that may get attention in 6-8 weeks. After that, maybe ;-)

Comment: Well, is obviously not a race condition since the revision history say: Post Closed as "off-topic" by toro2k, Wayne Conrad, Uri Agassi, eugen, MikDiet, Undo

Comment: This was not a race condition. The fifth close vote was cast about 2 days ago.

Comment: When I visit the question it says 1 hour ago. I think you quoted the wrong text. :)

Comment: Hrm. My 30-second investigation suggests that the first vote (from toro2k) was cast on a different review task that was later invalidated. My guess is that that vote got wrongly counted in the end. Or it might just be a display issue. I'll have to dig deeper, although in the meantime this doesn't seem overly harmful.

Comment: @Mhmd The question was closed an hour ago with Undo's vote, but the vote before his was cast 2 days ago.

Comment: You should have probably stopped at 5 :P 6 seems like overkill. When you cast your overkill vote, did it close the question, or was it already closed? Did you do it through the review queue or in the wild?