# Question with six close votes can still be reviewed in the review queue

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I got [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/81469) for review in the Close Votes queue:

[image: Question with six close votes in the review queue]

Six people seem to have voted to close it, and it still lets me review it and add an additional close vote. I am aware of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27608/643262), but there it seems that two users cast the last vote simultaneously. Here, even if that has happened, it still lets me review.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those (6), (5) and (1) indicate the total number of close votes *and flags*. To check how many *close votes* there are, you can select Close and check the labels:

[image]
<sup>obviously, this is a different example than your question</sup>

But now that the question has been closed (and deleted, but that doesn't matter), I'm pretty sure the UI will ask you to reload the review item, and you won't be able to complete it.

It actually got *six* Recommend Closure flags, as [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKUhB.jpg) (moderator-only, so I've anonymized the flaggers) shows.