# Why new user is created everytime on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, new-users, sign-up

If i post any question using same email (not registered) on SO, I don't get same userid... If I clear cache / use new browser / post from diff. place.
This is me >> https://stackoverflow.com/users/260731/kv
Is there anyway I can again use this user?
I have not registered.

Answer (score 12):

Two key things:

> not registered

and

> I clear cache / use new browser / post from diff. place.

When you are not registered, StackOverflow uses a cookie to remember who you are.  If you lose that cookie or access StackOverflow from somewhere that can't use that cookie (because you "clear cache / use new browser / post from diff. place") you'll have a different account.  You need that cookie to access your account — for all intents and purposes the cookie ***is*** the account.

If you want to be able to do things like clear your cache or use your account from more than one machine, the solution is simple: register.

Comment: But when you register, THEY will know where you live.  And then it's only a matter of time before you're rounded up and sent away on the trains.  Don't you see what kind of fascist dictatorship you're enabling by forcing people to register?

Comment: @Holocryptic: shouldn't you nickname be Hypocritic?

Answer (score 3):

If you provide an email address in your postings, you can use the "forgot your login information?" link on the `/login` page to email yourself a link that reinstates your cookie.

If you did not provide an email address.. you're out of luck.

As others have said, your best bet is to register.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely option is that you've deleted the cookie that identifies you

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can again use this user? I have not registered.

Just register yourself, then you can use it again. That's the whole point of registration.