# Question migrated from SO to SU has cloned itself

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978724/can-a-finalized-closed-dvd-be-modified-closed) has been migrated from SO to SU.  But it appears twice on SU: [201502](https://superuser.com/questions/201502/can-a-finalized-closed-dvd-be-modified) and [201503](https://superuser.com/questions/201503/can-a-finalized-closed-dvd-be-modified), both appear in listings.

Comment: Similar issue that was marked `[status-completed]`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19299/possible-race-condition-with-migration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hmm, looks like a race condition on close. I cleaned up and we'll look into it.

edit: we identified a bug in our code that could allow this, and fixed it.

Comment: Another one has appeared, same symptom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991618/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-switching-to-linux-from-mac-os-x to http://superuser.com/questions/202068/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-switching-to-linux-from-mac-os-x and http://superuser.com/questions/202070/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-switching-to-linux-from-mac-os-x

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a race condition to me.

> migrated to superuser.com by John Rasch **(1)**, Dustin Laine **(2)**, Kibbee **(3)**, ar **(4)**, Shiraz Bhaiji **(5)**, martin clayton **(6)** 25 mins ago

(emphasis mine)

Apparently you and Shiraz Bhaiji voted to close at exactly the same time, and the system migrated it twice in near-parallel.

Comment: Good spot that.

Comment: Personally, I blame ar for sneaking in there with a two-letter username.

Comment: This has happened before.  I recall one that got up to 14 close votes and 10(!) migrations.  (Was probably a different cause, then, though.)

Comment: @Roger: Yeah, I remember that one too; thought about looking it up, but like you, I assumed it was a different cause. EDIT: Alright, here it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51307/extra-votes-to-migrate-lead-to-multiple-posts